# Is it correct and natural to say "the phone comes at 500 dollars" meaning it costs 500 dollars?

Tags: word-usage

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say the phone *comes at 500 dollars* meaning it costs 500 dollars? For example:

> We have a lot of phones on sale and this **phone comes at** 500 dollars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not sound natural in US English.

We sometimes say "this phone **goes for** 500 dollars" to mean that that is the price: [definition 4 in Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/go-for), "If something goes for a particular price, it is sold for that amount."

Or maybe "this phone **comes out to** 500 dollars": *comes out to* implies something like "arrives at, after every addition and subtraction is taken into account"; we might use this structure something like

> This phone is normally 720 dollars, but after your employee discount and the credit you have on your account, it comes out to only 500.

Or maybe, less commonly, "this phone **comes in at** 500 dollars", which is similar to "comes out to" in implying that this is a final price after adjustments are taken into account.

But mostly I would just say the phone **costs** 500 dollars or **is** 500 dollars.

Comment: When totalling a set of costs we can say (e.g.) 'the TV costs $500, the shoes are $50 and the phone comes in at $500'. At least in Britain.